# C pointer concept segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf, c-strings, implicit-conversion

Please take a look of snippet: I am not able to understand why code is giving segmentation fault and garbage characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *str[1];
    str[0] = "apple";

    char **ptr = str;
    char *p = str;

    printf("%d\n", ptr);  //---> 1956347328
    printf("%d\n", p);      //---> 1956347328

    printf("%s \n", *ptr, ); // ---> prints apple
    printf("%s\n", *p);    // ---> error segmentation fault
    printf("%s\n", p);    // ---> Garbage characters    
}
```

Comment: You should get a warning about `char *p=str;`. The type of `str` is `char**`, not `char *`.

Comment: Don't use `%d` format to print a pointer, use `%p`.

Comment: @Barmar ptr and p are holding the same value , whats the difference ?

Comment: `*p` is `char`, but you pass it to `printf` with `%s` specifier which expects a pointer to a null-terminated string. So you get segfault

Comment: Types make a difference. Since `p` is declared `char*`, when you use `*p` it just extracts one byte from the memory that `p` points to. That won't be a valid pointer.

Comment: printf("%c\n",p);    // ---> getting garbage character , not the first character 'a' @Barmar

Comment: The value of `p` is the same as of `&str[0]` which is also not a valid pointer to string, but a pointer to a pointer, so you get garbage (you could get segfault here too).

Comment: `p` is not a `char`, it's a pointer.

Comment: Please make sure you've enabled maximum warning level in your compiler. It will warn you when the format operator doesn't match the argument type.

Comment: ok thanks, but this should work printf("%c\n",*p);  this is also not working

Comment: You told the compiler `p` is a `char *` but it points to a `char **` (as your code sample shows).  `char * str[1];` declares an array of size of that holds a pointer to a `char *`.  Let's call the address `A` and it's value is `A2`.  If you want the first character you need first deference `A2` but you deference `A`.  Also you have have two pointers `p` and `ptr` of different types referencing the same object which violates the strict alias rule so this is undefined behavior.

Comment: It looks like you forgot to enable a good set of warnings.  For GCC, I recommend `-Wall -Wextra` as a minimum; consider also `-Wpedantic -Warray-bounds` for identifying some other common mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a detailed explanation of the posted code behavior and problems:

- `char *str[1];` defines an array of pointers to `char` with a single element.
- `str[0] = "apple";` might trigger a warning as you store a pointer to a string literal, which must not be modified, into an element of the array which contains pointer to modifiable data. As long as you do not use this pointer to actually try and modify the string, you are safe.
- `char **ptr = str;` defines another object, a pointer to a pointer to `char`, intialized to point to the array `str`.  No problem with that, but you can only access the element at `ptr[0]`.
- `char *p = str;` defined another object, a pointer to `char` initialized to point to the array `str`.  This is a type mismatch as the type of `str` is neither *array of `char`* nor *pointer to `char`*, hence the compiler should issue a warning.  Yet as long as you only use this pointer to access the bytes that compose this array, you are safe.  The array contains a single pointer (that points to the `"apple"` string), which on your 64-bit machine is composed of 8 bytes.
- `printf("%d\n", ptr)` has undefined behavior because `printf` expects an argument of type `int` for the `%d` format, and you pass a `char **` value. On your architecture, integers and pointers seem to be passed in the same register or stack area, so `printf` outputs an integer that is a part (the low 32 bits) of the pointer, `1956347328`.  You should instead use `printf("%p\n", (void *)ptr);`
- `printf("%d\n", p)` same remark as above, the output is the same because both pointers point to the same address, but as they have different types, dereferencing them produces different things.
- `printf("%s \n", *ptr, )` is a syntax error, but without the extra `,` `printf` receives `*ptr`, which is the first element of the array `str`, ie: the `char *` pointer to the string `"apple"`, which is what it expects for  `%s`.  `printf` outputs the string `apple`, a space and a newline.
- `printf("%s\n", *p)`: `printf` receives `*p`, which is the `char` at the beginning of the `str` array.  This byte is the first byte of the pointer to the string, which has one of 256 possible values for such a pointer, in the range `CHAR_MIN` to `CHAR_MAX` (0..255 or -128..127 depending on the signedness of type `char`).  `printf` expects a pointer to `char` as the argument for the `%s` conversion.  Passing the `char` value has undefined behavior, and the value used by `printf` in your case is an invalid pointer: dereferencing it causes a segmentation fault.
- `printf("%s\n", p)`: the pointer `p` is passed to `printf` for the `%s` conversion, which is fine, but `printf` reads and outputs the bytes it points to until it reads a null byte.  These bytes are not those of the string `apple`, they are the bytes that compose the pointer stored in `str[0]`, which look like garbage values when output as characters. If `printf` did not find a null byte as it reads them, it would invoke undefined behavior whren reading past the end of the array and possibly cause a segmentation fault too.

Consider this modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void dump(const char *s, void *addr, size_t len) {
    printf("%s is at address %p, contains:", s, addr);
    unsigned char *p = addr;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
        printf(" %02x", p[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
    char *str[1] = { (char *)"apple" };
    char **ptr = str;
    char *p = (char *)str;

    dump("str ", &str, sizeof(str));
    dump("ptr ", &ptr, sizeof(ptr));
    dump("p   ", &p, sizeof(p));

    dump("*ptr", *ptr, sizeof("apple"));

    printf("*ptr as string: %s\n", *ptr);
    printf("*p   as byte  : %02x\n", *p);

    return 0;
}
```

I get this output on my macbook:

```
str  is at address 0x30cb5f278, contains: 6b ef 3d 04 01 00 00 00
ptr  is at address 0x30cb5f270, contains: 78 f2 b5 0c 03 00 00 00
p    is at address 0x30cb5f268, contains: 78 f2 b5 0c 03 00 00 00
*ptr is at address 0x1043def6b, contains: 61 70 70 6c 65 00
*ptr as string: apple
*p   as byte  : 6b
```

If I run the same executable again, I get different output because of address space randomisation, a technique used to make it more difficult for hackers to exploit software vulnerabilities.

The output shows that:

- the 3 objects `p`, `ptr` and `str` have a size of 8 bytes.
- they are located in memory in adjacent places (in stack, below the `main` arguments).
- `p` and `ptr` point to the area occupied by `str`: the address `0x3085b8280` is stored in little endian order, ie: from the least significant byte to the most significant byte.  This looks like *reverse order* but the order in which to store the bytes of a pointer (or integer) is only a matter of convention, just like the order of parts of speech in a phrase vary from one language to another.
- the string `"apple"` which contains the bytes `61 70 70 6c 65 00` is located at address `0x1023dff58` (a constant data segment).
- `*p` has the value `6b` which is a `k`, but, on my laptop, this value varies from one run to another as explained here above.

Answer (score 2):

`char *p=str;` is an incompatible pointer type initialization as `str` is a `char *[1]`.  Perhaps you mean `char *p = *str`?

`printf("%d\n",ptr)` is not the way you print a pointer.  On my system an `int` (for `%d`) is 4 bytes and a pointer is 8 bytes.  Instead you should do `printf("%p\n", (void *) ptr)`.

`printf("%s \n",*ptr,);` is a syntax error due to the missing argument.

I think this is what you wanted:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char *str[1];
    str[0] = "apple";

    char **ptr = str;
    char *p=*str;

    printf("%p\n", (void *) ptr);
    printf("%p\n", (void *) p);

    printf("%s \n",*ptr);
    printf("%s\n", p); 
    printf("%c\n", *p);

}
```

and the output is:

```
0x7fffcb2bb178
0x563522724004
apple 
apple
a
```

Comment: WIll this  give first character 'a'  --> printf("%c\n",*p);

Comment: Everything with `p` is undefined behavior and `ptr` works as you expect.   What are you trying to do with `p`? Did you mean  `char *p = *str;` perhaps?

Comment: I want to check what the difference, if 'p' and 'ptr' are holding the same address. One difference I got from here is that one is a character pointer, only pointing to the first character.  to check my understanding  I tried this --> printf("%c\n",*p); , which as you said undefined behavior

Comment: `p` and `ptr` are different types.  They should NOT hold the same address.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays used in expressions with rare exceptions are implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements.

So the array `str` declared like

```
char * str[1];
```

used as an initializer in these declarations

```
char **ptr = str;
char *p=str;
```

is converted implicitly  to a pointer of the type `char **`.

For the second declaration the compiler should issue a message that there are used incompatible pointer types: `char *` and `char **`.

These calls of `printf`

```
printf("%d\n",ptr);  //---> 1956347328
printf("%d\n",p);      //---> 1956347328
```

are invalid due to using the incorrect conversion specifier `d` designed to output objects of the type `int` with objects of pointer types. Instead you shall write

```
printf("%p\n", ( void * )ptr);    //---> 1956347328
printf("%p\n", ( void * )p);      //---> 1956347328
```

Nevertheless as it is seen from the output the both pointers contain the address of the first element of the array `str`. So dereferencing the pointer of the type `char **` you will get the first element of the array `str` of the type `char *` and thus can output the string pointed to by the element:

```
printf("%s \n",*ptr,);
```

In this call of printf

```
printf("%s\n",*p);
```

the expression `*p` has type `char`. As a result only one byte of the above shown address is read then promoted to the type `int` and is used as a valid address. As a result a segmentation fault occurs.

In this call of printf

```
printf("%s\n",p);
```

instead of using the value of the first element (pointer) of the array `str` as in this call

```
printf("%s \n",*ptr,);
```

there is used the address of the first element and the stored pointer value of the first element is outputted as a string.

Instead you could write for example

```
printf("%s\n", *( char ** )p);
```

making the call similar to the call

```
printf("%s \n",*ptr,);
```

that correctly outputs the string pointed to by the first element of the array `str`.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning a pointer to an array of strings (str[0] = "apple";).However str is declared as an array of pointers to characters.
you should use char str[] = "apple"; if you intend to use it as an array of characters.

char *p = str; is trying to assign a char **.
I think the following  code will help you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str[] = "apple";  // Correctly initialize str as an array of characters

    char *ptr = str;       // Use char * instead of char ** to assign the pointer to str

    printf("%p\n", (void *)ptr);  // Use %p to print pointers 
    printf("%p\n", (void *)str); //Print the address of the str(same as above line)

    printf("%s\n", ptr);   // Prints "apple"
    printf("%s\n",str);   //Prints "apple"
    printf("%c\n", *ptr);  // Prints 'a', accessing individual character
    
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
0x7ffc41ae4a02
0x7ffc41ae4a02
apple
apple
a
```